# how to navigate between screens in html5 firefox OS

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-os

How can I navigate between screens in Firefox OS HTML5 App.

There are activities in android, but how do I redirect to other screen I have in HTML5 App?

I am confused how to do that.

Comment: I think simple questions do not need complex descriptions. I do not understand why this question was closed... I'm working at Mozilla, and it's a question we got from developers not used with web technology, people coming from other platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Since Firefox OS applications are web applications using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, you can navigate trough pages, like you would do on the web:

```
<a href="page.html">link text</a>
```

or using JavaScript

```
window.location.href = "page.html";
```